# Text to Speech Locale Hindi Indian

Tags: android, locale, text-to-speech

I've created a Text to Speech Engine for Android that supports many languages, one of which is Hindi.

In the Android Text to Speech Settings, when the user selects a default locale, Android does a number of checks including sending the intent [ACTION_GET_SAMPLE_TEXT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.Engine.html#ACTION_GET_SAMPLE_TEXT)

Here is my list of supported locales:

```
private static final String[] SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES = { "eng-GBR", "eng-USA", "fra-FRA", "spa-ESP", "deu-DEU", "ita-ITA",
        "kor-KOR", "nld-NLD", "dan-DNK", "fin-FIN", "jpn-JPN", "nor-NOR", "pol-POL", "por-PRT", "por-BRA", "rus-RUS",
        "swe-SWE", "zho-CHN", "zho-HKG", "zho-TWN", "ara-SAU", "hi-IN", "ces-CZE", "ell-GRC", "hun-HUN", "ron-ROU",
        "slk-SVK", "tha-THA", "tur-TUR", "cym-GBR", "isl-ISL", "in-IDN" };
```

For every Locale other than "hi-IN", Android sends this intent and I respond with the example text and the "Listen to an example" button becomes available.

I'm successfully returning [LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE) from the call to [onIsLanguageAvailable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeechService.html#onIsLanguageAvailable%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), but the buttons remain greyed out and it states that the language is not supported.

I've tried so many different ISO combinations of the locale:

hin-IN, hi-IND, ind-HI etc etc etc, but Android doesn't send the Intent, despite it being labelled correctly in the Locale list as Hindi(Indian) or just Hindi.

There are no errors in the logcat to suggest a failed variant match.

There's little point me posting my code, as Android simply doesn't send the Intent for this Locale, so it doesn't get to reach my code....

Any ideas how to correctly handle this locale variant?

EDIT: I've just realised it's also happening for Indonesian (in-IDN)

Comment: Try `hin-IND` and `ind-IDN` for Hindi and Indonesian, respectively.

Comment: @shoerat Thank you so much! I swear blind I tried those combinations?? Anyhow, if you place your comment in an answer, I'll award you the bounty. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TTS uses 3-letter codes<sup>*</sup>  for [language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes) and [locale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3). So, based on that language/country code for:

```
Hindi         hin-IND
Indonesian    ind-IDN
```

Hope this helps.

---

**This needs a proper citation from sources: I just made my conclusion based on existing TTS engine implementations.*

Comment: Is there any other settings for hindi?.. I tried this code, but its failed to speak in hindi..:(

Comment: @KomalSorathiya, make sure that the engine you are testing against actually supports Hindi TTS.

Comment: That's not really a device specific feature, it depends on the TTS engine. Go to Settings -> Language & input -> Text-to-speech output and check the supported languages by the installed engines.

Comment: Can we install more text to speech output??.. I want to install that for Hindi.

Comment: Yes, search for 'TTS engine' at Play Store