# Android text to speech for Indonesian

Tags: android, locale, text-to-speech, android-4.2-jelly-bean

hey i'm trying to create a `tts` for 3 different language
they are English, Spanish, and Indonesia
i got no problem with English and Spanish
they work fine, but i got an error with the Indonesian language
i tried different ways and different locale combination but still no luck

here is my code for Indonesia :

```
Locale locInd = new Locale("IDN");

int result = tts.setLanguage(locInd);
```

I've tried `locale("in","ID");` ,  `locale("ind","IDN");` ,  `locale("in_ID);`
but also still no luck
every time i tried, the output is in English rather then Indonesian

i used jellybean(4.2.2) emulator to run it
and there is `in_ID` in locale when i run the emulator

EDIT :
i found my problem, in pico TTS indonesian is not installed
is there a tutorial where each time there is not supported language
it will pop up to ask for install?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598587/text-to-speech-locale-hindi-indian

Comment: Check this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android) check there

Answer (score 3):

```
MainActivity.tts.setLanguage(new Locale("id","ID"));
```

I used that and it works!

And apparently your phone must support Indonesian language. I tried on 2 different phones, one of them can't speak Indonesian

Answer (score 0):

set the language while initialising text to speech whenever you change the locale:

```
textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(context, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
     @Override
     public void onInit(int status) {
         switch (status) {
             case TextToSpeech.SUCCESS: {
                 synchronized (this) {
                         int result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(set the indonesia id here);
                  // Take action based on the result of initialisation

                 }
             }
             break;
             default: {
                 Toast.makeText(appContext, appContext.getResources().getString(R.string.tts_init_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
             break;
         }
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `"id", "ID"` or `Locale("id", "ID")` and not work you can try this code

**Kotlin :**

```
private fun askSpeechInput(){
    if(!SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Speech recognition is not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }else{
        val i = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "id-ID")
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Coba ucapkan sesuatu")
        launchSomeActivity.launch(i)
    }
}
```

This work for me